# missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete' django-audit-log

Tags: django, django-auditlog

I'm trying to have logs on one of my models by using the `django-audit-log` package. I've installed the package using pip and added `'audit_log.middleware.UserLoggingMiddleware',` to my middleware classes in my settings.py

In my `models.py` file, I have imported the necessary...

```
from audit_log.models.fields import LastUserField, LastSessionKeyField

class Transaction(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  updated_by = LastUserField()
  update_session = LastSessionKeyField()
```

This is exactly how they have implemented those fields in the documentation at https://django-audit-log.readthedocs.io/en/0.7.0/change_tracking.html#tracking-who-made-the-last-changes-to-a-model
Hence I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Even when I update the `updated_by` field to include the `on_delete` argument, I get the same error when I try and make migrations.
What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show the error traces?

Comment: I've decided that I don't need the package so I've gone ahead and implemented the `def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):` method in my model admin and I've gotten rid of the package entirely.